# GeneXus Unir varios archivos PDF físicos en uno solo

Tags: java, pdf, genexus, genexus15, genexusxev3

Se quiere saber si desde GeneXus 9.0 y/o Evo 3 se puede unir varios pdf que se encuentran físicamente en una ruta (archivos ya generados) y generar uno nuevo que contenga todo, han tenido alguna experiencia similar? o alguna orientación de como se podría realizar? y a partir de qué versión de Gx se puede realizar lo requerido.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: fíjate el UC PDF Tools. Tiene la opción de concatenar varios archivos pdf. Nunca lo use como para ayudarte, pero podes buscar algo de info por ese lado... Te dejo el link al marketplace https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?pdftools,es